# Why does subprocess command print 0 instead of path?

Tags: python

I'm beginner in python

I have tried following code. When I run code it doesn't give error, however expected output must be in file, instead it prints output on console.

In actual `test.txt` file it make entries as `0`.

Why does it print 0 and not the path returned by `pwd` command?

```
from subprocess import call

path = call('pwd')

with open('test.txt', "w") as f :
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(str(path))
    f.close()
```

Comment: Where did you read that `subprocess.call()` captures the command's output?

Comment: The `0` you see is the exit code from `call` meaning it finished its job successfully. As Ignacio says, `call` does not return its output stream.

Comment: Apart from that, the `f.seek()`, `f.close()` and the cast of `path` to `str` are not necessary.

Comment: try `call('pwd >test.txt')` without the `with..` part.

Comment: Instead use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output). It returns the output of the command, rather than its status code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get output from an external command, use [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) as noted by @Paul Rooney. You may change your program as follows to print the output of pwd to file:

```
from subprocess import check_output

path_bytes = check_output('pwd', shell=True)
path_str = path_bytes.decode('utf-8')

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(path_str)
```